# When purging messages by user and term, the wrong embed is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I've been working to create a Purge Command in JavaScript based off this [Purge Command written in TypeScript](https://sourceb.in/FJlualejle) for [reconlx's DJS v13 command handler](https://github.com/reconlx/djs-base-handler) (I modified a few bits to make all the handlers and whatnot function in DJS v14), however, there are some bugs and a few things I'm losing my mind over.

Firstly, everytime the command is enacted, this little nuisance of a message appears with the success confirmation embeds, and I don't really know how to deal with it.

[image: The little nuisance of a message I'm referring to]

Secondly, when I purge specifically by `user` and `term`, the wrong embed is sent and my bot will purge as normal. According to the source code, it (referring to my bot) should be sending the `cleanPurge` embed, but it instead sends the `userPurge` embed. Purging specifically by `user` works as intended, just with the annoying "thinking" message as an unwanted bonus.

Thirdly, when purging by `term`, I can only purge if I enact the command right after a message with the specified term. Here's an example (if you don't understand my wording).

```
// It is okay to purge during these situations

// cat in a hat
// cat in a hat
// cat in a hat

// /purge [amount: 3] {term: cat}

// The command will purge only if it is enacted right after the message with the specific term, however...


// The command won't purge during these situations

// cat in a hat
// cat in a hat
// cat in a hat
// SHITPOST

// /purge [amount: 3] {term: cat}

// The message "SHITPOST" is in-between the last message with the term "cat" and when I enact my command, 
// therefore, for some reason, I can't purge any messages with my specified keyword before the message "SHITPOST".

// I can purge messages with the term "cat" AFTER the message "SHITPOST" until another message gets in the way.

// If you have no idea what I mean, a link to my bot's demo is below.
```

Purging without specifics **DOESN'T** bring up the "{Bot} is thinking..." message and works as intended.

If you're confused, here's a [link to a demo of my bot's bugs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XfzzYljjeRREnYa2aojrt1zZOo_dTFqk/view?usp=sharing)

Any questions, please feel free to ask me, and sorry if my wording is shit.

Source code for `purge.js`

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ApplicationCommandOptionType, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js");
const { Command } = require("reconlx");
const ms = require("ms");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "purge",
    description: "Deletes a specified number of messages",
    userPermissions: PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages,
    options: [
        {
            name: "amount",
            description: "Number of messages to purge",
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer,
            min_value: 1,
            max_value: 100,
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "user",
            description: "Purge this member's messages",
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            required: false,
        },
        {
            name: "term",
            description: "Purge messages with this specific term",
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
            required: false,
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "Reason for purging",
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
            required: false,
        },
    ],

    run: async ({ interaction }) => {
        const amount = interaction.options.getInteger("amount");
        const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
        const term = interaction.options.getString("term");
        const reason = interaction.options.getString("reason") || "Unspecified";
        const channel = interaction.channel
        const messages = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch({ 
            limit: amount + 1,
        });

        if (user) {
            const userMessages = messages.filter((m) => m.author.id === user.id);
            const purged = await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(userMessages, true);

            const userPurge = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#2F3136")
                .setTitle(`  PURGED!`)
                .addFields(
                    {
                        name: `Cleared ${purged.size} message${
                            purged.size > 1 ? "s" : ""
                        }!`,
                        value: `Any messages from \`${user.tag}\` have been deleted from ${channel}!`
                    },
                    {
                        name: `User`,
                        value: `\`${user.tag}\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Term`,
                        value: `\`Unspecified\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Reason(s)`,
                        value: `\`${reason}\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                )

            interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [userPurge] });
        } else if (term) {
            const filteredTerm = messages.filter((m) =>
                m.content.toLowerCase().includes(term)
            );
            const purged = await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(filteredTerm, true);

            const termPurge = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#2F3136")
                .setTitle(`  PURGED!`)
                .addFields(
                    {
                        name: `Cleared ${purged.size} message${
                            purged.size > 1 ? "s" : ""
                        }!`,
                        value: `Any messages with the term ||\`${term}\`|| have been deleted from ${channel}!`
                    },
                    {
                        name: `User`,
                        value: `\`Unspecified\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Term`,
                        value: `||\`${term}\`||`,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Reason(s)`,
                        value: `\`${reason}\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                )

            interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [termPurge] });
        } else if (term && user) {
            const memberMessages = messages.filter((m) => m.author.id === member.id && m.content.toLowerCase().includes(term));
            const purged = await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(memberMessages, true);

            const cleanPurge = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#2F3136")
                .setTitle(`  PURGED!`)
                .addFields(
                    {
                        name: `Cleared ${purged.size} message${
                            purged.size > 1 ? "s" : ""
                        }!`,
                        value: `Any messages from \`${user.tag}\` with the term ||\`${term}\`|| have been deleted from ${channel}!`
                    },
                    {
                        name: `User`,
                        value: `\`${user.tag}\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Term`,
                        value: `||\`${term}\`||`,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Reason(s)`,
                        value: `\`${reason}\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                )
                
            interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [cleanPurge] });
        } else {
            const purged = await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(messages, true);

            const purge = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("#2F3136")
                .setTitle(`  PURGED!`)
                .addFields(
                    {
                        name: `Cleared ${purged.size - 1} message${
                            purged.size > 1 ? "s" : ""
                        }!`,
                        value: `The specified number of messages have been deleted from ${channel}!`
                    },
                    {
                        name: `User`,
                        value: `\`Unspecified\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Term`,
                        value: `\`Unspecified\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: `Reason(s)`,
                        value: `\`Unspecified\``,
                        inline: true
                    },
                )
            interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [purge] });
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend to edit your post and add your code here instead of comments!

Comment: Corrected my mistake. Source code is now in post.

Comment: For one, you should probably de-quadriplicate that embed building. You already have variables – use them when building the message.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Be sure you're asking a single clear, specific question which is reflected in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video is still processing, so I couldn't watch it, but:

In the "cat"/"cat"/"cat"/"shitpost" situation, you'd need amount=4, because you're only fetching N + 1 messages. If you need want your bot to purge N last matching messages even if there are more in between (e.g. in a "a"/"b"/"a"/"b"/"a"/"b" situation where you want to purge all "b"s), you'd need to fetch more messages until you've purged enough. Another "good enough" option might be to fetch e.g. `amount * 2` messages and hope it's enough.

In any case, you could start by de-quadriplicating your message filtering and embed building:

```
{
  run: async ({ interaction }) => {
    const { options, channel } = interaction;
    const amount = options.getInteger("amount");
    const user = options.getUser("user");
    const term = options.getString("term");
    const reason = options.getString("reason") || "Unspecified";
    const lastNMessages = await channel.messages.fetch({
      limit: amount + 1,
    });
    const filteredMessages = lastNMessages.filter((message) => {
      if (user && message.author.id !== user.id) {
        return false;
      }
      if (term && !message.content.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    const purged = await channel.bulkDelete(filteredMessages, true);
    const title = `Cleared ${purged.size} message${purged.size > 1 ? "s" : ""}!`;
    const message = [
      `${purged.size} messages`,
      user ? ` from \`${user.tag}\`` : "",
      term ? ` containing \`${term}\`` : "",
      ` have been deleted from ${channel}!`,
    ].join("");

    const userPurge = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#2F3136")
      .setTitle(`  PURGED!`)
      .addFields(
        {
          name: title,
          value: message,
        },
        {
          name: `User`,
          value: user ? `\`${user.tag}\`` : "Unspecified",
          inline: true,
        },
        {
          name: `Term`,
          value: term ? `||\`${term}\`||` : `\`Unspecified\``,
          inline: true,
        },
        {
          name: `Reason(s)`,
          value: `\`${reason}\``,
          inline: true,
        },
      );
    await channel.send({ embeds: [userPurge] });
  },
}
```